# Getting nohup to properly exit after running application

Tags: bash

I have a program that runs indefinitely. I which to run this program remotely by issuing the following command:

```
nohup mono program.exe &
```

Although I'm able to close the terminal and still have program.exe running, I would like nohup to return me the command prompt ($), so that I can issue more commands before terminating.

How do I go about doing this?

Cheers

**Answer (or workaround)**

Do an explicit redirection of the standard output and errors streams

```
nohup mono program.exe >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the command in the way described above, you will get back the command prompt.

You are executing it in the background. So, you should get back the command prompt before terminating the process program.exe. This is not the case!!!?

Comment: Agreed, as long as you have "&" it should return you to the prompt.  Perhaps Mystic is running this from something other than a normal terminal window?  It doesn't sound like it though...  Mystic?  More information please?

Comment: Based on what I thought should have happened, I agree that I probably should have gotten the prompt. My program busy-waits (with 1 second sleeps) on the main thread. It doesn't block on input from the terminal. I doubt if that is causing the problem, or is it?

Comment: @Mystic: Just try this: "$ nohup sleep 20 &". You should get the prompt without waiting for 20 seconds. Your application execution should behave in a similar way!

Comment: Tried that using both putty and the ssh client that comes with Cygwin. Neither works. I need to hit the return key in order to see the prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mystic: So it is ok if you can do it without waiting.

Comment: No, I really need to get the prompt back without having to hit return.

Comment: Alright, I figured this out. I had to do an explicit redirection of the standard out and error streams, i.e, nohup mono program.exe >> nohup.out 2>&1 &. Interesting don't you think? Btw, is nohup available on most Linux distributions?